# jump from one Activity to another Activity(with 3 Fragments), the Fragment is invisible

Tags: java, android-fragments

Below are two Activities:

Test_Result.java

```
Intent  intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("flag","data");
intent.setClass(Test_Result.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mainPager=(MyViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vPager);
    radioGroup=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.bottom_bar);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    flag = intent.getStringExtra("flag");
    if (flag == null){
        initViews();
        radioGroup.getChildAt(2).performClick();
    }
    else {
        if (flag.equals("test")) {
            initViews();
            radioGroup.getChildAt(0).performClick();
        }
        if (flag.equals("data")) {
            initViews();
            radioGroup.getChildAt(1).performClick();
        }
        if (flag.equals("info")) {
            initViews();
            radioGroup.getChildAt(2).performClick();
        }
    }
}

private void  initViews(){
     fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
     fragments=new ArrayList<Fragment>();
     testFragment=TestFragment.getInstance();
     dataFragment= DataFragment.getInstance();
     informationFragment=InformationFragment.getInstance();

     fragments.add(testFragment);
     fragments.add(dataFragment);
     fragments.add(informationFragment);

     mainPager.setAdapter(new MainPageAdpter(fm));       
 }
```

When it jumps,there is no view in 3 fragments except radioGroup.
But when I open the app, three fragments are there in MainActivity.
Why? I just began to learn Android two weeks ago and I am innocent, please help me.

Comment: How are you sending the fragments to adapter?

Comment: sorry，I cannot explain because i use other‘s demo

Comment: can I Email you to tell you details？thanks vvvvvv